# Efficiently calculate next permutation of length k from n choices

Tags: algorithm, permutation

I need to **efficiently** calculate the next permutation of length `k` from `n`
choices. Wikipedia lists [a great
algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Generation_in_lexicographic_order)
for computing the next permutation of length `n` from `n` choices.

The best thing I can come up with is using that algorithm (or [the Steinhaus–Johnson–Trotter algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steinhaus%E2%80%93Johnson%E2%80%93Trotter_algorithm)), and then just only considering the first `k` items of the list, and iterating again whenever the changes are all above that position.

Constraints:

- The algorithm must calculate the next permutation given nothing more than
  the current permutation. If it needs to generate a list of all permutations,
  it will take up too much memory.
- It must be able to compute a permutation of only length `k` of `n` (this is
  where the other algorithm fails

Non-constraints:

- Don't care if it's in-place or not
- I don't care if it's in lexographical order, or any order for that matter
- I don't care *too much* how efficiently it computes the next permutation,
  within reason of course, it can't give me the next permutation by making a
  list of all possible ones each time.

Comment: I am pretty sure you'll find your answer in the code for the Python itertools module, having a look

Comment: yeah it's an *.so on mac os x, so i was too lazy to go find the source. guess i should stop being lazy and go do that.

Comment: http://hg.python.org/releasing/2.7.3/file/7bb96963d067/Modules/itertoolsmodule.c#l2497

Comment: http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations

Answer (score 1):

You can break this problem down into two parts:

1) Find all subsets of size `k` from a set of size `n`.

2) For each such subset, find all permutations of a subset of size `k`.

The referenced Wikipedia article provides an algorithm for part 2, so I won't repeat it here. The algorithm for part 1 is pretty similar. For simplicity, I'll describe it for "find all subsets of size `k` of the integers `[0...n-1]`.

1) Start with the subset `[0...k-1]`

2) To get the next subset, given a subset `S`:

2a) Find the smallest `j` such that `j ∈ S ∧ j+1 ∉ S`. If `j == n-1`, there is no next subset; we're done.

2b) The elements less than `j` form a sequence `i...j-1` (since if any of those values were missing, `j` wouldn't be minimal). If `i` is not 0, replace these elements with `i-i...j-i-1`. Replace element `j` with element `j+1`.